# Why p$\frac{\partial }{\partial P} $ is the mean of binomial distribution function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Why p$\frac{\partial }{\partial P}[ {p+q}]^n $ is the mean of binomial distribution function? I know the mean should be $\sum np(n) $ but why p$\frac{\partial }{\partial P} [{p+q}]^n$ of the binomial distribution is the mean. And i dont see that to be used in Poisson or Gaussian distribution.  So why is this  the mean ?

Comment: Is this some sort of bizarre typo?  The binomial $B(n,p)$ will have mean $np$.

Comment: @Randall does it loik right now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem),

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i\binom{n}{i}p^iq^{n-i}=p\times\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left(p^iq^{n-i}\right)=p\times \frac{\partial}{\partial p}(p+q)^n
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.